# Reiniciar contador a 1 en php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo una duda a ver si alguien me puede ayudar
En lo que estoy desarrollando necesito que el día 1 de cada mes por ejemplo el numero de averías empiece por 1 y después por supuesto le vaya añadiendo 1 consecutivamente. Ya para el día 2 es ir obteniendo el ultimo y irle sumando 1, lo tengo echo que obtenga el ultimo y me le sume 1 pero en el resetear en el día 1 me lo hace bien en el primero pero después me mantiene el 1, estoy medio enredado con eso.

Tengo este codigo

```
$dia = date("d");

foreach ($max_id as $maximo):
//Obtengo el numero maximo de averia
$maxID = $maximo['nro_averia'];
//extraigo los 3 ultimos digitos que es lo que necesito
$nueva_averia = substr($maxID, -3);

 $contador=0;
 //Si es el dia es 1 lo pongo a 1
 if ($dia == 1 && $contador==0){
    $nueva_averia = 1;
    $contador=1;
 } else {
    $nueva_averia += 1 ;
 }
 endforeach;
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Entiendo que estas trabajando con una base de datos, y dados que lo que quieres obtener es un dato calculado, por que no simplemente lo haces en la consulta ordenando los registros por fecha?

Comment: Porque no calculas el campo en la sql?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más detalles del contexto, no sea que haya una mejor forma de solucionar tu problema?  Por ejemplo, ¿es una base de datos?, ¿cuál es el criterio que determina la fecha, es una columna que guarda ese dato, es la fecha del sistema, etc?

Comment: Te explico, yo obtengo el numero de la averia de la base de datos, el cual es un numero conformado de la siguiente manera año-mes-numero averia (ejemplo 18-7-0025) obtengo el ultimo numero de la averia y le sumo 1 cuando se le da a agregar la averia nueva. Ahora cuando empieze el nuevo mes ese numero debe ponerse en 1 y asi ir sumando en ese mes. Lo quiero que lo haga una sola vez ese dia y despues siga sumando de uno en uno. Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mejor te lo desarrollo paso a paso, si no entendiste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es la tabla que le llamare config y ahora vamos con el codigo

conect.php

```
<?php
    //********************************
    //   Y U R I C O
    //********************************
    $connect = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ayuda';
    try {
            $db = new PDO($connect,'root','ascent');
            $db->setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
?>
```

e1.php

```
<?php
    //********************************
    //   Y U R I C O
    //********************************

    include ('conect.php');

    $configSQL = 'SELECT mes,averia FROM config';
    $config = $db->prepare($configSQL); 
    $config -> execute();
    $db_mes='';
    $db_averia='';

    $dia = substr('00'.date("d"),-2);
    //$mes = substr('00'.'08',-2);   Simules el mes y lo pruebes
    $mes = substr('00'.date("m"),-2);


    while ($resp = $config -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
            $db_mes = $resp->mes;
            $db_averia = $resp->averia;
    }               

    if ($db_mes!=$mes){
        $db_averia=1;
        $db_mes=$mes;
    }else{
        $db_averia = $db_averia + 1;        
    }
    $actualizaSQL = 'UPDATE config SET mes = :MES , averia=:AVERIA';
    $actualiza = $db->prepare($actualizaSQL); 
    $actualiza -> bindValue(':MES', $db_mes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $actualiza -> bindValue(':AVERIA', $db_averia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $actualiza -> execute();

    $codigo = $dia.'-'.$mes.'-'.substr('0000'.$db_averia,-4);
    echo "codigo -> ".$codigo."<br>";

    // aqui ya tu lo guardas las averias en otra tabla
 ?>
```

así queda, espero te sirva, saluditos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

amigo espero que te sirva esta ilustración para tu mejor entendimiento la puedes adaptar.

```
<?php
    // averia =   99  999 
    //           dia  incremental   
    $dia = date("d");
    echo "Dia->".$dia."<br>";
    $d = rand(1,31);
    echo "---------<br>";
    echo "Dia Simulado->".$d."<br>";
    echo "---------<br>";   
    if ($dia!=1){
        $averia=rand(0,998); // simula lo que va acumulando la averia es to es a 333 digitos
    }
    if ($dia==1){
        $averia=0;
    }
    $averia++;
    $codigoaveria = substr('00'.$d,-2).substr('000'.$averia,-3);
    echo "Codgio de Averia -> ".$codigoaveria;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Codigo Para uso -> ".substr('000'.$codigoaveria,-3);
 ?>
```

Comment: Te explico, yo obtengo el numero de la averia de la base de datos, el cual es un numero conformado de la siguiente manera año-mes-numero averia (ejemplo 18-7-0025) obtengo el ultimo numero de la averia y le sumo 1 cuando se le da a agregar la averia nueva. Ahora cuando empieze el nuevo mes ese numero debe ponerse en 1 y asi ir sumando en ese mes. Segun la solucion que me das mientras el dia sea 1 me seguira dando el numero de averia siempre en 1, eso quiero que lo haga una sola vez ese dia y despues siga sumando de uno en uno. Gracias por el aporte